# how to enable narrowing conversion in function parameter

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion

how to enable narrowing conversions in functions or constructors, that is you're allowed to pass types that require narrowing conversion, without the need to use static_cast explicitly

```
struct Position
{
    float x;
    float y;
    Position(float x, float y) : x{ x }, y{ y } {}
};
```

```
Position p{1, 1};
```

Comment: The question looks answerable to me, but your code did not demonstrate the issue when I compiled it.

Comment: @OP: The issue you want to ask about will not actually occur if you put constant `1`s into the constructor arguments. You need to use a (non-const) variable to hold `1` instead. So please edit your question if I am not mistaken about what you want ask about.

Comment: Braced init-list is designed/used to prevent this. Why do you want to circumvent this.

Comment: `Position p(1, 1);` will avoid the restrictions on narrowing conversions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***Note:** I do not endorse this approach, but at the same time I think there is value in knowing it.*

The warning about a narrowing conversion is legitimate (it is a potential bug), so it should be handled somewhere. If you do not want users of your class to worry about it, you can add constructors to cover all scenarios and put the casts in your constructors.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct Position
{
    float x;
    float y;

    template <class Number> requires std::is_arithmetic_v<Number>
    Position(Number x, Number y) :
        x{ static_cast<float>(x) }, y{ static_cast<float>(y) }
    {}
};
```

Of course, with this approach, it's on you if these casts cause bugs. This might be acceptable in a stand-alone program, but I would strongly advise against it for re-usable (library) code.

---

A better approach is to normalize the types used to store coordinates. If your choice is `float`, you could make an alias for that to give this choice semantic weight.

```cpp
using Coordinate = float;

struct Position
{
    Coordinate x;
    Coordinate y;

    Position(Coordinate x, Coordinate y) : x{ x }, y{ y } {}
};
```

With this approach, if `Coordinate` is used consistently when calculating coordinates, a narrowing conversion is an even more likely sign of an error that should be addressed rather than papered over.

The choice is yours. Suppress warnings and risk bugs, or respect the warnings and have a better chance at bug-free code.